# INT16 - Big Endian (AB) convert to hex and ascii

Tags: c#

I want to convert hex and ascii from INT16 - Big Endian (AB) data type. But I don't know how to continue. [I want to do similar work in extension.](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) I want to get character from first int singned or unsingned data type.

example :The Modbus pool program can do this.

[image]

display-> hex select

[image]

convert to ascii and hex

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of input/output here, so we can see what you mean? I'm very familiar with all the bits involved here, but knowing exactly what you're expecting would really help

Comment: example:
input value int 16 = 568 
output value = #8
The Modbus pool program can do this.

Comment: The [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=net-5.0) class will let you extract the representation of a numeric value (an `int`, say) as a byte array. You can then manipulate those bytes are convert them back to binary. This should let you do everything that the page that you link to is doing.

Comment: You did it correctly the first time. Posting an answer to your question is the appropriate way to indicate the question has an answer. You are even able to accept your own answer by clicking the gray checkmark next to your answer (after undeleting it of course).

Comment: I can't answer questions right now. How do I overcome the obstacle? @HenryEcker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved

```
int Int16Values=568;
string hexString=Int16Values.ToString("X4");
 try
        {
            string ascii = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                string hs = string.Empty;

                hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
                ulong decval = Convert.ToUInt64(hs, 16);
                long deccc = Convert.ToInt64(hs, 16);
                char character = Convert.ToChar(deccc);
                ascii += character;
            }

            return ascii;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
Console.WriteLine(ascii);
```